Registering Multiple Policies For Same Model
I have issue when i am trying to set multiple policies for same model.
Example:
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        Model::shouldBeStrict();

        Gate::policy(Company::class, CompanyPolicy::class);
        Gate::policy(User::class, UserPolicy::class);
        Gate::policy(User::class, DispatcherPolicy::class);

        Paginator::defaultView('vendor.pagination.tailwind');
    }
}

It is only registering UserPolicy. I have workaround for it but it would be awesome if i could have do it with Gate facade...
This is workaround:
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;

trait AuthorizationTrait
{
    protected string $policyClass = '';

    public function setPolicyClass(string $policyClass): void
    {
        $this->policyClass = $policyClass;
    }

    public function isAbleTo($ability, $parameters = [])
    {
        try {
            $instance = new $this->policyClass;
            if (method_exists($instance, $ability)) {
                $authorized = $instance->$ability(auth()->user(), ...$parameters);
                if (!$authorized) {
                    abort(403, 'This action is unauthorized.');
                }
                return $authorized;
            }
            return false;
        } catch (AuthorizationException $exception) {
            abort(403, 'This action is unauthorized.');
        }
    }
}


I have tried setting directly what policy should Gate facade look for
Example: Gate::authorize('viewAny', [DispatcherPolicy::class, ...$params])


add a layer of middleware
register policy with auth service provider class

